# Google Maps Javascript API only loads data, when console is open

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display a map on my page, which sets a marker.

**What's my problem**

The map instance works without any problems. There is no error in the console or from Google at self. But unfortunately, the map data is not loading. I just get the Google logo and a grey background, as you can see on the picture.
[image: Grey map from Google Maps API]

Then, when I open the console of Google Chrome, it loads the map data and it display me the map with the requested map type.

[image: Loaded data after opening the developer console]

**What I tried**

I searched in the internet, found some other problems like the grey box, but the solution doesn't help me.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
   //Just some example coordinates
   var lat = 47.8;
   var lon = 8.9
   var location = {lat: lat, lng: lon};
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: location,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
   });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't think it's the console but the fact that when you open the console, the windows is resized and so it may trigger something that force the redrawing of the map. To try that, you can reload your page with the console already opened (if I'm right the map will be grey).

Comment: Ah yes, okay there must be something with the resize. It will be also grey if the console is open and I reload it. What can I do?

Comment: Can you give me a test please? Change the width of your map to a pixel size

Comment: @LucasTorres I tried it but unfortunately the same result.

Comment: Try removing "async defer"

Comment: @LucasTorres No also the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not perfect but you can try to force the resize when the maps is loaded :

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize'); 
});
```

Or without jQuery:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', () => {
    const event = new Event('resize');
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It loads via a AJAX command. What I have to do with this command?

Comment: I updated my answer so the timeout is now triggered when the map is loaded, if that works, you can propably try without the timeout.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I removed then the setTimeout and it just works.

Comment: Perfect, I will remove it from the answer to then!

Comment: REFER: http://jsfiddle.net/Jf4JH/2/    OR  ` <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>` specify dimension in pixel will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You Shouldn't need to add a DOM Listener. The map should just load with this script:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

and the initMap function.

EDIT: 
The DOM Listener is waiting for you to "load" the DOM so is waiting for you to open teh Console before loading the map.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. But it didn't solves my problem.